# Cordova was listed on the list of requirements for third-party SDKs announced by Apple. How can we get Privacy Manifest file or create it?

Tags: cordova, policy, privacy

Recently Apple announced a list of SDKs where cordova was one of them which has to meet the new data privacy requirement. A privacy manifest file for the same needs to be added within the projects Which are using it.

As per the Apple Documentation:

Starting in spring 2024, you must include the privacy manifest for any SDK listed below when you submit new apps in App Store Connect that include those SDKs, or when you submit an app update that adds one of the listed SDKs as part of the update. Signatures are also required in these cases where the listed SDKs are used as binary dependencies.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=r1henawx#

Can anyone please let us know on how to proceed on this by giving a step by step procedure to meet the new requirement

It would be helpful if there is any documentation for this from the Apache Cordova team to deal with this new requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Detailed step by step process to handle the new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

See the issue from the [Cordova Ios Repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1391)

TLDR: it's unclear the implications and Cordova, Flutter and other frameworks are kind of waiting after Apple to understand what they even mean/want.

Comment: Can we ignore this during the app publishing process until we get a warning or error from Apple?